# Does char data type in SQL start from 0?

Tags: sql, types

Does the char data type in SQL start from 0, so for example if I declared the attribute ID CHAR(1) would that attribute be able to have 2 characters or just 1?

Comment: `CHAR(1)` is for 1 character.

Comment: First rule of asking a question; try it for yourself first.  Create a variable or column with `CHAR(1)`, populate it with a two character string, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

ID CHAR(0) will raise an exception. The minimum value should be 1 which is also the default value.
To answer your question ID CHAR(1) will have 1 character.